# Can I create a Gradle plugin that adds a dependency or another plugin based on a Gradle extension value?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Can I create a Gradle plugin that adds a dependency based on an extension value?

I have a convention plugin that I use for libraries various projects, which brings in various dependencies, takes care of boilerplate configuration, configures other plugins etc etc. I want to add an extension to the plugin that can tell the plugin whether or not to add a certain dependency, in this case it happens to be Spock, as not every library module needs the Spock dependency.

So far, my plugin looks like this

```
interface BasePluginExtension {
    Property<Boolean> getUseSpock()
}

class BasePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        BasePluginExtension basePluginExtension = project.extensions.create('basePluginConfig', BasePluginExtension)

        // If a value was supplied, use it, otherwise assume we want Spock
        if (basePluginExtension?.useSpock?.get() ?: true) {

            // Printing for debugging purposes
            println "I'm using spock! ${basePluginExtension.useSpock.get()}"
            
            // Currently apply a plugin that applies Spock but could also just add a dependency
            project.plugins.apply("test-config")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `build.gradle` file that I want to pull my plugin into, I have

```
plugins {
   id 'base-plugin'
}

basePluginConfig {
    useSpock = true
}
```

I'm following the docs on [configuring an extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot query the value of extension 'basePluginConfig' property 'useSpock' because it has no value available.
```

I've also tried the method of making an abstract class for the extension but I want the ability to have multiple configurable parameters in the future.

Is adding a dependency after plugin extension values have been configured not allowed/out of order for how Gradle works? Or am I possibly missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm not totally sure that there is a good solution, but I think the problem here is a lifecycle problem. Calling `basePluginExtension.useSpock` in your code snippet is too early.

I think you need to use `afterEvaluate` https://discuss.gradle.org/t/custom-plugins-how-to-avoid-using-afterevaluate-when-setting-another-plugins-extension-configuration/42314/7

Comment: Agreed- definitely a lifecycle issue. After evaluate seems to give me what I need, so thanks for the tip! I need to do more reading into where that *really* falls in the Gradle lifecycle so I don't follow the "Lifecycle abuse" I've seen some mention.

I also needed to add a convention (default value) for my extension object which was easy to add!

`basePluginExtension.useSpock.convention(true)`